# Meteor / accounts-google: Where is the client secret stored? Is it safe?

Tags: meteor, google-oauth, meteor-accounts

After adding packages accounts-google and accounts-ui, and adding {{> loginButtons}} to my meteor app's html, I'm presented with the following button:
[image]

This allows me to enter my client id + secret - fantastic!

Where are these stored?

If I'm able to set them without having to login or somehow prove that I'm the owner of the app, does this mean that anybody could set them to something new, by making the same request to my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the configuration keys, it won't ask you/your user to enter these credentials again. These secrets are stored in your database, to be specific it is stored in this collection`meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration`. And yes when you're adding the accounts-ui package, all things including securities are done by that package as this package is maintained by `mdg(meteor development group)`. So you can be sure that no one can make request to change/update your credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, I can see my id + secret in that collection.

I don't quite understand the security model well enough. It feels strange that anybody could set the tokens the first time round. Would you happen to have an explanation what's preventing anybody from changing it later on?

Comment: From my understanding, when someone is using this `google` or any other login service, your meteor app looks for credentials in that collection, if found it shows you the login modal,otherwise accounts-ui package asks for you to enter the credentials. and any update or delete operation is restricted from the client side (may be using allow/deny). Thus if you want to reset/change this credentials, you have to delete the information from the mongo shell manually and then the accounts-ui package will ask you to enter credentials again.